# Django custom save decorator causing Internal Error in formset saving (inline in admin)

Tags: python, django

I have a custom save method and a custom decorator for it to run the Django's model save() before and after my custom save:

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

def save_decorator(method_to_decorate):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(type(self), self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        method_to_decorate(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super(type(self), self).save(*args, ** kwargs)
    return wrapper



class The_Image_Abstract(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    create_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)


class Avatar(The_Image_Abstract):
    #I'm using this to track Avatar class in the template. There should be a better way.

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='avatar')

    @save_decorator
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        "my stuff here"
        pass
```

This works perfectly when Avatar is saved or modified in the admin page. But it raises Internal Error when Avatar is saved as formset in an inline of another model (formset worked before adding the decorator).
What is going wrong here? I saw posts about people receiving this error when using Postgres and I am using Postgres too but I don't think this case is caused by Postgres.

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:     http://localhost/admin/auth/normal_user/add/
Django Version:     1.4.3
Exception Type:     InternalError
Exception Value:     

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Exception Location:     /home/eras/projects/kart/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql, line 912
Python Executable:     /home/eras/projects/kart/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Eras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the reason why this is happening. It had to do with the decorator trying to save the model before some non null fields which had no default value were set. I'm not still sure why it was causing error only when saving new objects in Admin inlines (formset). But setting those mandatory fields to some value before running the custom save function solved the problem.